# How to define list of int and defaultdict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, function

I want to define a list of an integer and defaultdict in python.
I am creating a parent dictionary which shall return the above list.

I am being unable to define the list type.

```
def index_struct():return defaultdict(list_struct)
def list_struct(): return list(int,post_struct)
def post_struct(): return defaultdict(list)
```

Currently getting an error as list cant take two args..

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to create types?

Comment: it shall be easy to access them using just indexes

Answer (score 2):

You're right that *list()* only takes one argument.  Use the square brackets notation instead.  Also note the `[int, post_struct]` won't work because nothing is calling the two constructors.  You need to call the constructors manually by adding parentheses:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def index_struct():return defaultdict(list_struct)
def list_struct(): return [int(), post_struct()]
def post_struct(): return defaultdict(list)

>>> d = index_struct()
>>> d['somekey'][0] = 5
>>> d['somekey'][1]['anotherkey'] = 6
>>> d
defaultdict(<function list_struct at 0x10252ff50>, {'somekey': [5, defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'anotherkey': 6})]})
```

Comment: Isn't `int()` just a slow way of saying `0`?

Comment: Yes it is :-)  That said, I mirrored the OP's approach as closely as possible so he could see where his error was (i.e. the constructors not getting called).  Precomputing ``int()`` would have made the answer more difficult to understand relative to the original posting.

Comment: Hey thanks.Got my mistake.Was not calling the constructor.Have one more doubt, when is it better to define struct types and when to use a class instead